# Spray painting popcorn ceiling

Tags: ceiling, spraypainting, popcorn

I am going to paint our 1970s popcorn ceiling and walls. I will be using an airless paint spray (rental from Homedepot) for both the ceiling and walls.

I’ve taped off the trim, windows, and doors, but I’m wondering how I can protect the ceiling (I’ll spray them first)when I spray the walls. After the paint dries, will 2 inch painters tape be extended enough for any splatters? Will it even stick? Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Thats the period when asbestos was used on textured ceilings.  So, I would be careful not to disturb it.  If it was me, I would get it checked, for peace of mind.

Answer (score 1):

Paint the walls first, then run tape around the perimeter and drop painters plastic over the walls. This will prevent overspray on the walls while doing the ceiling.

I like to run a hand masker around the perimeter of the ceiling, on the walls and spray onto that, sometimes paint will flake off the plastic and can cause issues, with the paper there, you won't have that issue.

This is how we did it 90% of the time, other times I would spray the lid (2 coats) and then spray the walls, you'll get some overspray on the ceiling but not much if you watch your fan. Once the walls dry, we would run just a hand masker around the perimeter with 12" paper and do a spray back on the ceiling and roll it. Personally, I stick with the first option.